# Finding $T(x)$ where $T$ is a linear transformation defined with respect to a (non-standard) basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ be a linear transformation such that $T(-2,3)=(-1,0,1)$ and $T(1,2)=(0,-1,0)$. Note that $B=\{(1,2),(-2,3)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^2$ and calculate $T(0,-1).$

What's the procedure?

I found $T(0,-1)=(1/7,2/7,-1/7)$ don't know if that's correct.

Comment: Hint: Can you write $(0,-1)$ in terms of the basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes. I tried and I can.

Comment: Okay, I'll follow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $B=\{(1,2),(-2,3)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Now, in the first place you require

$\tag 1\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=p\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix} +q\begin{pmatrix}-2\\3\end{pmatrix}$.

which means

$p-2q=0$

$2p+3q=1$.

Solving, you get

$q=\frac{1}{7}$ and $p=\frac{2}{7}$.

Now applying $T$ to $(1)$ and using linearity, you get

$$T\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\frac{2}{7}T\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix} +\frac{1}{7}T\begin{pmatrix}-2\\3\end{pmatrix}$$

and now to finish, substitute the data you are given.

Answer (score 1):

Let there be a matrix $A$ that
$$A\begin{pmatrix}-2\\3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},\quad
A\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
Then
$$A\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\3&2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
If there is a vector $\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\end{pmatrix}$ that satisfies
$$\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\3&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$
Then 
$$\begin{align*}
A\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix} &= 
A\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\3&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\end{pmatrix}\\&=
\begin{pmatrix}-p\\-q\\p\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$

---

**Edit** or in a pure linear transformation perspective:

If there is a pair of scalars $p,q$ that satisfies
$$p\begin{pmatrix}-2\\3\end{pmatrix} + q\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then by linearity of $T$,
$$\begin{align*}
T\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix}
&= T\left[p\begin{pmatrix}-2\\3\end{pmatrix} + q\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}\right]\\
&= T\left[p\begin{pmatrix}-2\\3\end{pmatrix}\right] + T\left[q\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}\right]\\
&= p\ T\begin{pmatrix}-2\\3\end{pmatrix} + q\ T\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}\\
&= p\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} + q\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}-p\\-q\\p\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: $A\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf v_1&\mathbf v_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}A\mathbf v_1&A\mathbf v_2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I couldn't apply your solution in the problem, can you give me a hint?

Comment: It is about finding $p$ and $q$ by solving this matrix equation:$$\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\3&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$ or this vector equation: $$p\begin{pmatrix}-2\\3\end{pmatrix} + q\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$ which is the same as the suggestion from @MichaelBurr above: write $(0,-1)$ in terms of the given basis.